# I want to apply for-each loop on two models at same time Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view

I want to apply for each loop on two models at the same time.

**My Controller Action Is:**

```
public ActionResult MarkAttendance(int id)
{
    var students = _context.Students.Where(c => c.ClassId == id).ToList();
    var status = _context.Statuses.ToList();

    var viewModel = new AttendanceViewModel
    {
        Student = students,
        Status = status
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**My Student Model is**

```
 public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z\s]{1,}[\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\s]{0,}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid name. Use letters only")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z\s]{1,}[\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\s]{0,}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid name. Use letters only")]
    [Display(Name = "Father Name")]
    public String FatherName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 10000)]
    public int Fee { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^((\+92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter only mobile number, Landline not acceptable")]
    [Display(Name = "Student Contact No.")]
    public string StudentContact { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter correct phone number")]
    [Display(Name = "Guardian Contact No.")]
    public string GuardianContact { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Enter only numbers")]
    [Display(Name = "Roll Number")]
    [IfRollNoExists]
    public int RollNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Record Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Student Picture")]
    public String ImageURL { get; set; }

    public Class Class { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Class Title")]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }


}
```

**My Status Class is**

```
  public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string StudentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

**My ViewModel Is:**

```
public class AttendanceViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> Student { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Status> Status { get; set; }
}
```

**My Razor View is:**

```
@model  Pioneer.ViewModel.AttendanceViewModel
@foreach (var student in Model.Student)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@student.Name</td>
        <td>@student.RollNo</td>
        <td>
            <div data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-success active">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status.StudentStatus, "Present", new { id = "1" })
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-danger">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status.StudentStatus, "Absent", new { id = "2" })
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status.StudentStatus, "On Leave", new { id = "3" })
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-warning">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status.StudentStatus, "Short Leave", new { id = "4" })
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>                                           
    </tr>
}
```

Now when I am getting error for using

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status.StudentStatus, "Present", new { id = "1" })
```

Below I attached an image of error. [Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xERm6.png)

And please tell me can I iterate over my rows without using for-each if I use HTML helper here?

Comment: First of all your viewmodel name and class name both are **Status**, Change it and then try again. Are you sure **StudentStatus** is within **Status**, because there is no description of model

Comment: u have some broken logic here

Comment: Please mention clear what you want to acheive.

Comment: @anete.anetes I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. As per your view code, the `Status` model should be part of `Student` model class class.

**So your view Model will look like this :**

```
public class AttendanceViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

**And Student model class will include status :**

```
public class Student
{
    public IEnumerable<Status> Status { get; set; }
}
```

**Now you can access status in your view like this :**

```
@model  Pioneer.ViewModel.AttendanceViewModel       
@foreach (var student in Model.Student)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@student.Name</td>
        <td>@student.RollNo</td>

        @foreach(var status in student)
        {
            <td>
                <div data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-success active">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(status.StudentStatus, "Present", new { id = "1" })
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-danger">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(statusStudentStatus, "Absent", new { id = "2" })
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(status.StudentStatus, "On Leave", new { id = "3" })
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-warning">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(status.StudentStatus, "Short Leave", new { id = "4" })
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>  
        }
    </tr>
}
```

**EDIT :**

Or if you're particular about using the same ViewModel as mentioned in the question, you can replace `foreach` with `for`. Check below sample code :

```
@model  Pioneer.ViewModel.AttendanceViewModel
@for(var studentIndex = 0; studentIndex < Model.Student.Count(); studentIndex++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.Student[studentIndex].Name</td>
        <td>@Model.Student[studentIndex].RollNo</td>

        @for(var statusIndex = 0; statusIndex < Model.Status.Count; statusIndex++)
        {
            <td>
                <div data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-success active">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status[statusIndex].StudentStatus, "Present", new { id = "1" })
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-danger">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status[statusIndex].StudentStatus, "Absent", new { id = "2" })
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status[statusIndex].StudentStatus, "On Leave", new { id = "3" })
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-warning">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status[statusIndex].StudentStatus, "Short Leave", new { id = "4" })
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>     
        }       
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I have tested both the solutons and it seems to work fine at my end. Did you try both the solutions mentioned in the answer? What error are you getting now?  @AlamzaibFarooq

Comment: In the nested loop, it's giving the error that `student` is not enumerable. **For each loop cannot iterate Pioneer.Models.Student**

Comment: **My Controller**


`public ActionResult MarkAttendance(int id)
        {
            var students = _context.Students.Where(c => c.ClassId == id).ToList();
            var status = _context.Statuses.ToList();

            var viewModel = new AttendanceViewModel
            {
                Student = students
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }`

Comment: I resolved the issue in the nested loop. Now I am not able to access `status` properties. When I write in radio button `status.StudentStatus` its not recognizing `StudentStatus`

Comment: Can you check with the `@for` method I mentioned rather than the `@foreach` method? @AlamzaibFarooq

Comment: In second method its giving an error that **statusIndex does not exist in the current context.**

Comment: You are using statusIndex before declaring it. I used `studentIndex` instead of `statusIndex` its giving error that **Cannot apply indexing on enumerable**

Comment: both variables have separate uses. I think you dont get the point. studentIndex for accessing the first for loop and status index is for accessing the second for loop.

Comment: Yes, I am understanding. How can you use `statusIndex` even before declaring it? I know they both have the purpose. I am getting the error that's why I am saying.

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq : Oops.. sorry..that was a mistake. I corrected

Comment: I got the issue. I was using the same name

 `public IEnumerable<Student> Student { get; set; }`

Comment: Your first method is correct! I should have used `Students` instead of `Student`

Answer (score 1):

**`m.Status` its `IEnumerable<Status>`, it's have not `StudentStatus` property.**

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status.StudentStatus, "Absent", new { id = "2" })
```